# Finding application icons within an iTunes iOS backup

Tags: ios, backup, itunes

Is it possible to extract an iOS application's icon from its files within a locally stored iTunes iOS backup? I've searched the backup manifest and app related files and can find the list of installed apps, but no icons. Currently I am using the domain name as an input to the Apple iTunes search API.

e.g.:

for "com.facebook.Messenger"
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Messenger&entity=software

Ideal would be to extract from the backup files directly.

Answer (score 0):

I remember at the time of 16 years, the time can also access to the application of through itunes. The ipa file and then through the ipa file modification extension into the. Zip file, directly open the can get the current English local resources, and then from the Payload folder to find the app file, right-click the display file content, can be read into the application of more local resources, basic inside it will include the app icon resources and Assets inside pictures, and so on

Unfortunately, I also forgot that the specific time was 17 years ago. This function was cancelled by an update of Itunes. However, we can still get the.ipa file package of the App with the help of three party tools in MAC, such as PP assistant and iToos. Then the relevant local resources of the application can be obtained through the method I just described

l hope help you

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions.